# figure out 2 strings similar or not

Tags: c, string

Rules:
2 strings, a and b, both of them consist of ASCII chars and non-ASCII chars (say, Chinese Characters gbk-encoded).

```
If the non-ASCII chars contained in b also show up in a and no less than the times they appear in b, then we say b is similar with a.
```

For example:

```
a = "ab中ef日jkl中本"  //non-ASCII chars:'中'(twice), '日'(once), '本'(once)
b = "bej中中日"  //non-ASCII chars:'中'(twice), '日'(once)
c = 'lk日日日'   //non-ASCII chars:'日'(3 times, more than twice in a)
```

according to the rule, b is similar with a, but c is not.
Here is my question:
We don't know how many non-ASCII chars are there in a and b, probably many.
So to find out how many times a non-ASCII char appears in a and b, am I supposed to use a Hash-Table to store their appearing-times? 
Take string a as an example:

```
[non-ASCII's hash-value]:[times]
     中's hash-val      : 2
     日's hash-val      : 1
     本's hash-val      : 1
```

Check string b, if we encounter a non-ASCII char in b, then hash it and check a's hash-table, if the char is present in a's hash-table, then its appearing-times decrements by 1.
If the appearing-times is less than 0 (-1), then we say b is not similar with a.

Or is there any better way?

**PS:**
I read string a byte by byte, if the byte is less than 128, then I take is as an ASCII char, otherwise I take it as part of a non-ASCII char (multi-bytes).
This is what I am doing to find out the non-ASCII chars.
Is it right?

Comment: You can't read the string byte-by-byte unless you know the encoding.  If the strings are presented to you as real strings of characters, then the encoding has been done for you.  You mean "read the string character by character and **if the codepoint** of the character is less than 128 it is ASCII."

Comment: Your example assumes `>=` but the rules say just "more than" i.e., `>`.

Comment: @Ray Toal, What I'm doing is this: for(int i=0; i < strlen(a); i++) { char tmp = a[i]; ...}, is this right?

Comment: @J.F., sorry, I'll re-edit it .

Comment: @Alcott, oh you didn't tag it C, so I assumed a modern language like Java which properly distinguishes characters and bytes.  Since you are using PLAIN one-byte chars in C, then you will simply HAVE to ask the interviewer what encoding is being used.  Or did the interviewer not say?  Is this a language independent question?

Comment: @Ray, now I tagged it c. What am I supposed to know the encoding for? Knowing or not knowing the encoding makes what difference?

Comment: Because characters are encoded differently in different character sets!  For example, see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm.  It occupies 3 bytes in UTF-8, 2 bytes in UTF-16, and 4 bytes in UTF-32.

Comment: I've written [script that demonstrates difference between various strategies to segment a string into characters](http://ideone.com/oEY2g): as bytes, as codepoints, as codepoints in NFC form, as grapheme clusters. 'bytes' method fails on the example from your question for utf-16 encoding; codepoints method breaks on examples with combining symbols e.g., a=u'\xea', b=u'e\u0302' (both are 'ê' character); normalized codepoints don't pass tests based on Devanagari kshi ('क्षि'). As a reference I've used `/\X/` regexp that implements http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have asked two questions:

1. Can we count the non-ASCII characters using a hashtable?  Answer: sure.  As you read the characters (**not the bytes**), examine the codepoints.  For any codepoint greater than 127, put it into a counting hashtable.  That is for a character c, add (c,1) if c is not in the table, and update (c,x) to (c, x+1) if c is in the table already.
2. Is there a better way to solve this problem than your approach of incrementing counts in a and decrementing as you run through b?  If your hashtable implementation gives nearly O(1) access, then I suspect not.  You are looking at each character in the string exactly once, and for each character your are doing either an hashtable insert or lookup and an addition or subtraction, and a check against 0.  With unsorted strings, you *have* to look at all the characters in both strings anyway, so you've given, I think, the best solution.

The interviewer might be looking for you to say things like, "Hmmmmm, if these strings were actually massive files that could not fit in memory, what would I do?"  Or for you to ask "Well are the string sorted?  Because if they are, I can do it faster...".

But now let's say the strings are massive.  The only thing you are storing in memory is the hashtable.  Unicode has only around 1 million codepoints and you are storing an integer count for each, so even if you are getting data from gigabyte sized files you only need around 4MB or so for your hash table (or a small multiple of this, as there will be overhead).

In the absence of any other conditions, your algorithm is nice.  Sorting the strings beforehand isn't good; it takes up more memory and isn't a linear-time operation.

**ADDENDUM**

Since your original comments mentioned the type `char` as opposed to `wchar_t`, I thought I'd show an example of using wide strings.  See http://codepad.org/B3MXOgqc

Hope that helps.

**ADDENDUM 2**

Okay here is a C program that shows exactly how to go through a widestring and work at the character level:

http://codepad.org/QVX3QPat

It is a very short program so I will also paste it here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>

char *s1 = "abd中日";
wchar_t *s2 = L"abd中日";

int main() {
    int i, n;
    printf("length of s1 is %d\n", strlen(s1));
    printf("length of s2 using wcslen is %d\n", wcslen(s2));
    printf("The codepoints of the characters of s2 are\n");
    for (i = 0, n = wcslen(s2); i < n; i++) {
        printf("%02x\n", s2[i]);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
length of s1 is 9
length of s2 using wcslen is 5
The codepoints of the characters of s2 are
61
62 
64
4e2d
65e5
```

What can we learn from this?  A couple things:

1. If you use plain old `char` for CJK characters then the **string length will be wrong**.
2. To use Unicode characters in C, use `wchar_t`
3. String literals have a leading `L` for wide strings

In this example I defined a string with CJK characters and used `wchar_t` and a for-loop with `wcslen`.  Please note here that I am working with real characters, NOT BYTES, so I get the correct count of characters, which is 5.  Now I print out each codepoint.  In your interview question, you will be looking to see if the codepoint is `>=` 128.  I showed them in Hex, as is the culture, so you can look for `>` 0x7F. :-)

**ADDENDUM 3**

A few notes in http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Unicode-HOWTO-6.html are worth reading.  There is a lot more to character handling than the simple example above shows.  In the comments below J.F. Sebastian gives a number of other important links.

Of the few things that need to be addressed is normalization.  For example, does your interviewer care that when given two strings, one containing just a Ç and the other a C followed by a COMBINING MARK CEDILLA BELOW, would they be the same?  They represent the same *character*, but one uses one codepoint and the other uses two.

Comment: Thanks, Ray. Your answer is pretty clear. One more question, I don't understand why I can't read byte-by-byte but char-by-char? What I thought is "one char is one byte", wrong? Am I missing something out?

Comment: Well in C, the type `char` (as opposed to `wchar_t`) is guaranteed to be represented in 1 byte, but we all know Unicode provides for over a million characters so certain encodings use more than one byte to represent a character.  Modern languages tend to allow the programmer char-by-char access, doing the encoding/decoding behind the scenes.  Now, if your interviewer says the string is, say, ISO8859-1 which has 256 chars, you can go byte by byte because each char fits in 1 byte.  Do you have to use C for this?  And are you given `chars`?  If so, you will have to encode yourself.

Comment: @Alcott also see http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html if you have not already.  Apologies if you _have_ seen it, but I wasn't sure if the "one char is one byte" remark was referring to C or coding in general, so I thought I would reference it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Well, typically I read string the for-loop way "for(int i=0; i < strlen(a); i++) { char tmp = a[i]; ...}", do you mean that if I knew the encoding of a, I should do it another way (a different for-loop?), not just simply increment i by 1 every time ?

Comment: What I mean is that you need to know the encoding of `a` in order to determine how many characters you even have in your byte array.  Does your interview question say _anything_ about encoding, C, Unicode, multi-byte strings, `wchar_t` or anything like that?  Since you are using CJK characters I assume the easiest approach would be to use `wchar_t` instead of C and let C do the encoding work for you. :-)

Comment: @Alcott I added a link in my answer to C code that shows how to use wide strings.

Comment: you're pretty kind :-). The interviewer didn't say anything about the encoding. Typically, when I define a char* var in C like this: char *str = "abd中日"; then when I compile and run the program, C will automatically do the encoding job for the str variable? Let's assume the encoding is wchar_t, then I guess I can use strlen(a)/sizeof(wchar_t) to find out how many characters are there in a, right? If there are n chars in a, then can I still use the for-loop to read char by char from a? "for(int i=0; i < strlen(a); i+=sizeof(wchar_t)) {...}" increment i by sizeof(wchar_t), right?

Comment: I think I shouldn't use strlen with wchar_t strings.

Comment: Actually the adjustment for `sizeof(wchar_t)` is not necessary.  I only did that in my example to show encodings.  Give me a couple minutes and I will produce a new program for you that does _exactly_ what you want (I hope!) :-)

Comment: You can't always just store codepoints. The same user-perceived characters can be represented using different sequence of codepoints e.g., http://ideone.com/8qSe9 . [Unicode normalization forms](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/) should be at least mentioned. Enumeration of characters is not obvious also http://ideone.com/bl5vp See [Unicode text segmentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/).

Comment: Great examples @J.F.  Yes, a fully correct character-level task like this would required normalization (combining sequences, etc.), and yes, that should have been mentioned.  In fact, [the type wchar_t might not even have a Unicode encoding](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Unicode-HOWTO-6.html) and all that.  I suspect for an interview, a codepoint-level kind of counting should suffice.  After the OP gets hired, of course, things would get much more serious. :)

Comment: @Ray, thanks for your detailed answer, I just finished reading the article you linked, it's pretty good.

Comment: I've written [script that demonstrates difference between various strategies to segment a string into characters](http://ideone.com/oEY2g): as bytes, as codepoints, as codepoints in NFC form, as grapheme clusters. 'bytes' method fails on the example from the question for utf-16 encoding; codepoints method breaks on examples with combining symbols e.g., a=u'\xea', b=u'e\u0302' (both are 'ê' character); normalized codepoints don't pass tests based on Devanagari kshi ('क्षि'). As a reference I've used `/\X/` regexp that implements http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/

Comment: @Alcott: yes. The output of the script at [the end of the page I've linked](http://ideone.com/oEY2g). It shows on which a,b string pairs the tests fail. If you can read Python there is also an implementation of your algorithm in `issimilar_alcott()` function.

Comment: @J.F., every time when I simply define a char* variable in C, say char *str = "abd中日"; what is str's encoding? ASCII? What if I want to explicitly define a gbk or ISO-8995-1 string in C?

Comment: @Alcott: 1. whatever encoding your editor uses (It says nothing about a format that your toolchain chooses to produce binary executable). 2. No. there is no '中' in http://asciitable.com/ 3. Multiple encoding in a single file is not a good idea. Write it in your source encoding and convert to desirable encodings [programmatically](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html#Generic-Charset-Conversion). Create new question if you have specific problem.

Comment: @Ray Toal, sir, this is gonna be a little embarrassing, today I posted a question asked by an interviewer, hoping to get some help, but nobody answered it with being viewed 30+ times. I really hope that you can spare a little time helping me about it, here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425400/design-a-system-supporting-massive-data-storage-and-query. Thank you very much.