# Iterating through Unicode codepoints character by character

Tags: c++, unicode, character-properties

I've got a series of Unicode codepoints. What I really need to do is iterate through these codepoints as a series of characters, *not* a series of codepoints, and determine properties of each individual character, e.g. is a letter, whatever.

For example, imagine that I was writing a Unicode-aware textbox, and the user entered a Unicode character that was more than one codepoint- for example, "e with diacritic". I know that this specific character can be represented as one codepoint as well, and can be normalized to that form, but I don't think that's possible in the general case. How could I implement backspace? It obviously can't just erase the last codepoint, because they might have just entered more than one codepoint.

How can I iterate over a bunch of Unicode codepoints as *characters*?

Edit: The Break Iterators offered by ICU appear to be pretty much what I need. However, I'm not using ICU, so any references on how to implement my own equivalent functionality would be an accepted answer.

Another edit: It turns out that the Windows API does indeed offer this functionality. MSDN just isn't very good about putting all the string functions in one place. [CharNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647469%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is the function I'm looking for.

Comment: How do you define "character" in this context? Something that translates to a single visual grapheme?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Something like that. Ideally, what I'd mean is something that is entered by one key combination on the keyboard.

Comment: Unless and until you define character in terms of code points, no answer is possible.  Unicode defines only two things: code points and extended grapheme clusters.  It does not define character.  Please rephrase your question in terms of code points and/or extended grapheme clusters, or else define your terms with sufficient precision as to make possible a programmic solution, which you have not yet bothered to do.

Comment: @tchrist: Did you really have to go and post the *same* comment on *every* answer? I got it by reading it once.

Comment: @tchrist: You will also note that ICU calls theirs a CharacterInstance. Whilst I didn't define their relationship to codepoints, since if I knew that I wouldn't have a problem, I certainly did define how I expected them to behave- which should be enough. ICU gives the *exact* example that I used to define the behaviour of their "CharacterIterator".

Comment: "However, I'm not using ICU" Really, you should. This is after all what it is for. In order to do what `BreakIterator` does, you will need to be able to query the properties of unicode points to know if one can break between them or not. And that requires basically downloading the Unicode specification and building a table of codepoint ranges for different properties. Or you can just use ICU, which does it for you.

Comment: related: [Grapheme Cluster Boundaries](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries) see also [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7375398)

Comment: @NicolBolas: I could use ICU, which can do Unicode but has absolutely no idea how to be a C++ library- it's half excessive inheritance and heap allocation Java, and half error codes everywhere C. Or I could use the Windows API, which will very neatly back my own Unicode string class, which was actually written to exist in C++.

Comment: @tchrist: This is a bit late, but according to the Unicode Standard version 6.2, page 11: "Characters are the abstract representations of the smallest components of written language that have semantic value. They represent primarily, but not exclusively, the letters, punctuation, and other signs that constitute natural language text and technical notation." The document then goes on to provide a table illustrating the difference between a glyph and a character. If this is not a definition, then I don't know what is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ICU library.

http://site.icu-project.org/

for example:

http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classUnicodeString.html#ae3ffb6e15396dff152cb459ce4008f90

is the function that returns the **character** at a particular **character** offset in a string.

Comment: Because I checked their interface documentation and none of it deals with what I need? None of it will recognize "e with diacritic" as one entity, not two.

Comment: is it worth the effort? how common are those "e with diacritic" cases? Note that I have no idea, I'm just asking.

Comment: What is a character?  Unicode has code points, whose API you have just described, and it has extended grapheme clusters, which are accessible through break iterators or the `\X` regex metacharacter sequence.

Comment: @tchrist: The break iterator seems about right. However, I am not using ICU, so an answer would need to discuss an implementation of it. Admittedly, "Break Iterator" is not the name under which I would choose to look for such functionality and so I didn't see it.

Comment: And it has *characters* that correspond, if you like, to UTF-32 code points. Which is what I thought the original question was originally about.

Comment: @bmargulies: even in UTF-32, a codepoint is not a character.  UTF-32 deals away with surrogate pairs, but there are other issues such as diacritics.  Check out grapheme clusters in the [Unicode text segmentation annex](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/).

Comment: @AndréCaron I'm a member of the UTC. I do know this stuff, I just judged that the OP wasn't trying to go all the way there.

Answer (score 1):

The [UTF8-CPP](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) project has a bunch of clean, easy to read, STL-like algorithms to iterate over Unicode strings codepoint by codepoint, character by character, etc.  You can look into that for inspiration.

Note that the "character by character" approach might not be obvious.  One easy way to do it is to iterate over an UTF-32 string in normalization form C, which guarantees fixed length encoding.

Comment: It was my understanding that not *all* characters could be represented in form C.

Comment: Not aware of that ever causing a problem, but I could imagine that languages such as Vietnamese with an astounding number of diacritics causes a very large number of combinations for NFC.  However, you'd have to read the Unicode spec to figure if NFC can represent everything or not.

Comment: A "character by character" approach is not possible, because "characters" is not defined.

Comment: @tchrist: Indeed, the entire Unicode standard does not define the term "character".  However, there is a commonly accepted definition of 1 unit of display, which typically renders to a single glyph.  The basically corresponds to a full precomposed set of codepoints in NFC.  UTF-32 in NFC gives you what is closest to a single "character" per codepoint.

Comment: @Andre: This was pretty close, but apparently, there are both ICU and WinAPI functions that serve the whole purpose.

Comment: Being in Normal Form C doesn't mean that there are *no* decomposed combining characters in a string. It only means that the sequences that *can* be combined, *are*. You'll still find combining characters in an NFC string if you've got obscure combinations that haven't been given their own combined code point. For what it's worth, there are combined code points covering the possible letters and tone marks for Vietnamese.

Comment: @AndréCaron Are you talking about an extended grapheme cluster then?  That's what vim considers a character, for example.

Comment: @tchrist: I was thinking of "user-perceived characters", which are indeed [approximated by grapheme clusters](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries).